# [Android]Many Device not compatible with the application

Tags: android, google-cardboard, uses-feature

I recently published an app on play store. But, my app is not compatible with lot of mobile devices. Some of the devices are Moto X Play, Moto E3 Power etc.

I don't understand which `<uses-feature/>` is causing this issue. Here are all the feature which I am requesting in my application:

```
<!-- Make accelerometer and gyroscope hard requirements for good head tracking. -->
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer"
    android:required="true" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.sensor.gyroscope"
    android:required="true" />

<!-- Indicates use of Android's VR-mode, available only on Android N+. -->
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.software.vr.mode"
    android:required="false" />
<!-- Indicates use of VR features that are available only on Daydream-ready devices. -->
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.vr.high_performance"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />
```

My app is a VR video player. Also, I want my app to work only on phones with screen size between 4 inches to 6 inches, I have given `<compatible-screens/>` as follows:

```
<compatible-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:xlargeScreens="false" />
```

But, I don't understand what is causing my app to be incompatible with lot of android devices?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: i think VR mode is not available for the above stated devices

Comment: or you can check in the google play console that which devices are supported

Comment: @AmanVerma, VR mode is not a must required feature in my app.

Comment: google play filtered devices according to the uses-feature defined in the manifest. maybe thats y devices like moto x and E3 is showing under incompatible devices. did you try removing this feature and then check.. hope it is still in beta mode..

Answer (score 1):

Moto X Play and Moto E3 Power do not have Gyroscope.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: change the gyroscope and the accelerometre to required false and then use try catch forms in your code to control the behaviour of the app. Then test in some devices. Provably the problem is the required features and the compatibility with those features. Be carefull with this things